# how to post file contents with different formats in a single known format\struct

Tags: node.js, angular, base64, filereader

Using angular8 + node.js - Trying to figure out how to get (post) **file content** - no matter what format it is (**UTF8 or base64 or binary**, in my case) to the node middlewear function so afterwards I can encode it (if needed) to base64 format\structure.
I manage to do it when the file content is base64, but having troubles whenever it is binary.

See my code:
Client side: //modalRef.componentInstance is the reference of the modal window approving to upload the file

```
  modalRef.componentInstance.passResult.subscribe(result => 
  {
    if (result)
    {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = () => 
      {

        this.uploadFileContent(fileReader.result.toString());
      }
      fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
      //fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0], "ascii");

    }
    event.target.value = null;
    this.FileToUpload = null;
  });
```

This is the uploadFileContent method:

```
uploadFileContent(fileContent : /*string*/any)
{
    this.dataService.uploadFile(fileContent).subscribe();
}
```

This is the service method:

```
uploadFile(fileContent : /*string*/any) : Observable<any>
{
  let body =  
  { 
    file: fileContent
  };    
  return this.http.post<any>(<fileUploadUrl>, body, {
    withCredentials:true
  }).pipe(
    tap(res=>{
      console.log('file was uploaded!'); 
    }),
    catchError(error =>  this.doSomething(error))
  ); 
}
```

Server side:

```
router.use(schemaValidation(schema), (req, res, next) =>
{
   try
   {
       let file = req.body.file;
       //When receiving the file content in a single fortmat and struct - I would like to encode it 
         base64 format
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it simply by posting the file as a binary string.
instead of : 
fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);

I used:

fileReader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);